# ImageView larger than the screen as a background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, horizontalscrollview

Hello I have a ImageView(background) which's height should correspond to the screen height, the width on the other hand should be left intact.

Before this was done like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <HorizontalScrollView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/songDetails_songImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/songDetails_cd_songCover"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/default_song_cover" />

</HorizontalScrollView>  
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
...
```

This worked fine - the image view occupies whole background and the user can scroll right or left to see the whole image.

My goal is to animate the scroll, to do that I need to get rid of the horizontal view(to prevent user from scrolling) but whenever I change the HorizontalScrollView to Frame/Relative layouts(with the width set to wrap_content) the image view is scaled down to fit the screen.

Is there a way to keep the imageView width intact(with height matching that of the screen) so that it would remain bigger than the device screen?(without cropping)

I could then use custom animation to scroll right.

I have looked at similar questions but I wasn't able to find anything that would work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to try to override the onTouchListener for the HorizontalScrollView.

For example, something like this:

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouch());

private class OnTouch implements OnTouchListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
    }
}
```

This would disable  the user from scrolling the HorizontalScrollView while you could probably still scroll it programmatically.

Comment: I thought about that but isn't there a way I could do that without using HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: I'm not sure. You're saying the image is scaled down when you remove the HorizontalScrollView. You could try to play around with the ScaleType of the ImageView. If one of the available ScaleTypes works you could then try to do the 'scrolling' by using a translationX animation on the ImageView.

Comment: Aww tried probably every combination of ScaleType and AdjustViewBounds and every single one seems to be trying to fit the device screen. The way it does it is I have a couple versions of the same image in xxhdpi drawable folders, when I change the scaleType it simply picks the smaller image that fits the screen and displays it.